# Getting more voltage/amperage from the Raspberry Pi 2 GPIO pins

Tags: gpio, power, pi-2, battery

So yeah, I'm trying to get some more voltage/amperage from the **GPIO pins** on my **Raspberry Pi 2 Model B**.  I've ran several tests and I'm only getting about **3.2V and 30-40mA**.  This cannot do much, there must be a way that I can somehow get some more power, probably through an external power source such as a battery.  I've heard some things about sending small electrical signals to make something like this work.

The only problem with this is that I've no idea how I can do this, which is why I'm asking this question.

I want to do things such as lighting up a light bulb or something related to that, **3.2V and 30-40mA** just isn't gonna cut it.  A **9V battery**, on the other hand, can easily power something like this.

Thank you for any help, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I had this exact same problem.**

I needed ~6v ~1A from the GPIOs so I bought a boost converter, stripped a usb cable, attached + and - to the boost converter and put the output on a transistor, the base of that transistor was hooked up to a GPIO pin on my Pi.

---

There are better ways than that for turning on and off light bulbs.

Like using relays: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/home-automation-raspberry-pi

Or Arduino: http://www.instructables.com/id/Uber-Home-Automation-w-Arduino-Pi/

Comment: So, there's no way to just find a way to use the electrical signal as a switch to allow the external battery to give power to the lightbulb?  It's a small lightbulb by the way, it'll work with 3v easily.  It's not a bulb you'd have as a ceiling lamp or anything.

Comment: @ZacharyVincze see the link above for relays. Other possible solutions are to use a RF controlled socket, that can be controlled via WiFi, Bluetooth or 433mhz radio, using a transistor/darlington array to switch the 9V supply.